# sharing dict class attribute when using multiprocessing Manager

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I've written a bit of code that is intended to run via mutliprocessing and subprocess a bunch of Fortran executables. I've tried to create a simplified example us 'df' calls as linked below. I'm using multiprocessing on Ubuntu 12.04, everything is 2.7 python.

I create a dictionary on a class to use as a 'queue' and for record keeping. Perhaps I should use multiprocessing.Queue, but for the time being I'm not.

The first version is here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1076049/

If you run this code, you'll see that the dicts are not synchronized after the call to multiprocessing.... some googling and searching... then I learned about multiprocessing.Manager for sharing/synchronizing the dicts from searches on this site.

I tried to implement it here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1076054/

But now I get an error regarding the KeyError. This occurs at line 43 where I try to reference the key I just created (line 40) in the dict. This causes no errors in my first approach above, but clearly when using Manager.dict I am missing something.

Am I misunderstanding how to use the Manager class?

Comment: If you ever log on here again, post your code in the question (your paste links are dead) and I will try to answer your question. Ping me using @skrrgwasme in a comment on here to let me know you've added the code.